# How to have a if statement which is nested within a while statement only complete its function once

Tags: python, firebase

I'm trying to have my code only complete its process once. (If res = on only do it once but when it becomes off it detects that and does the off data encode once.) Here is my current code and my function onoff if needed as well

````
def onoff():
    result = firebase.get('/Data', 'Condition')
    return result

while True:
    res = onoff()
    data = res+","
    if res == 'on':
        ser.write(data.encode())
        print(data)
        time.sleep(1)
    elif ser.write(data.encode()):
        print(data)
        time.sleep(1)```
````

Comment: Do you want to exit the "while true" loop? If so use... break

Comment: I don't want it to exit the while loop as I do need it to detect and encode the data when it swaps from on to off or vice versa

Comment: `res = "NoLongerOn"` inside the if statement ?!?

Comment: res is reset to onoff( ) function each time. It pulls on (or off) and sets res to that. If I insert res = "NoLongerOn" it'll just be reset anyways and I can't remove the onoff function as I need to control something externally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it too work, had to include 2 switches to control it

```
    result = firebase.get('/Data', 'Condition')
    return result

switch = False
switch2 = True

while True:
    res = onoff()
    data = res+","
        
 
    if res == 'on':
        if run_once == 0 and switch:
            ser.write(data.encode())
            print(data)
            switch2 = True
            switch = False
            time.sleep(1)
    

    if res == 'off':
        if run_once == 0 and switch2:
            ser.write(data.encode())
            print(data)
            switch = True
            switch2 = False
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: if you switch them everytime into the opposite you can use only one with 'not switch'. Also with the current logic a reformating into on big if with `if run_once == 0` and then two smaller with the res and the switch check would be more intuitive to read

Answer (score 1):

````py
def onoff():
    result = firebase.get('/Data', 'Condition')
    return result
switch = True
while True:
    res = onoff()
    data = res+","
    if res == 'on' and switch:
        ser.write(data.encode())
        print(data)
        switch = False
        time.sleep(1)
    elif ser.write(data.encode()):
        print(data)
        time.sleep(1)```
````

Comment: Only problem I had with this is that the elif function will print on now. If I inserted another variable which is controlled by res I may be able to get something but not certain. Thanks a million for the help though!